# Fixing Error function 'long int map

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

[image]

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Users\julie_000\Documents\Arduino\BIO_199\BIO_199.ino: In function 'void loop()':

BIO_199:19: error: too few arguments to function 'long int map(long int, long int, long int, long int, long int)'

   t1 = map(2, 0, 1023, 2);

                         ^

In file included from sketch\BIO_199.ino.cpp:1:0:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:253:6: note: declared here

 long map(long, long, long, long, long);

      ^

exit status 1
too few arguments to function 'long int map(long int, long int, long int, long int, long int)'
```

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Use formatting! And don't post pictures of code!

Answer (score 4):

`map` takes 5 parameters, not 4.  You have the original lower and upper bounds, the desired lower and upper bounds, but you forgot the actual value you want to map:

```
map(value, fromLow, fromHigh, toLow, toHigh)
```

So

```
t1 = map(t2, 2, 0, 1023, 2);
```

(assuming those numbers are actually meaningful...)